# Can't add text after automatically numbering nets on a bus (Eagle 7)

Tags: eaglecad

In Eagle 7, when I draw a Bus line I can quickly assign a number of nets to the bus by using the [N..M] format; for instance, say i want to add data lines D from 0 through 8, I can Name the bus  D[0..8].

However, this fails if i add text after the last bracket: if I want to create a bus of differential pairs and i Name LVDS_[0..3]_P the command will fail, reporting " Unexpected '_' ", meaning subsequent characters are not allowed.

This is a very minor shortcoming, plus there are infinite ways of manipulating text outside of Eagle to automate text creation (Notepad++ is a favorite of mine), but i was wondering if anyone else came across this and perceived it as a limitation? Is there a way around it within Eagle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, there is no in software workaround beyond ULPs, text editors or scripts.

In the end I stopped using buses for things, and find it neater to just use labelled net stubs (short wire with a label on it).

For naming things in bulk, I made an excel file which generates scripts of name commands. This works well if things are on a regular grid (e.g. data pins of a symbol all equally spaced as you can quickly generate coordinates with a step and offset. A similar approach could be done by making a ULP that takes x/y/step and some name format.